# Auto Post/Tweet Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I tried auto-post feature of `Tweepy` API.

Here is the code:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
if api.verify_credentials():
    api.update_status('HELLO');
```

I tried logging `auth` it returns a value, tried returning `api` returns a value.
Thus meaning it has the right values, but then it always fail in the **`api.verify_credentials()`**

It also have an error showing this:
    **`[{Could not authenticate you', u'code': 32}]`**

Is there other settings I need to add, or what can be done for the tweet to work. I searched other answers its almost the same as mine. But what could be missing.

Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication key might change every time you click on the link (that was provided to generate the key). Make sure you are using the latest key that was generated.

Comment: Hi @raul, the process i have been doing is let the user allow my twitter app. Then when a different button is clicked, above code is execute.